# Stats and Probability question

Tags: statistics

Find the probability of being dealt a bridge hand
of 13 cards containing 5 spades, 2 hearts, 3 diamonds,
and 3 clubs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{hint:}$$52 \choose 5, 2, 3$$

Answer (score 2):

$$P={{{^{13}C_{5}}*{^{13}C_{2}}*{^{13}C_{3}}*{^{13}C_{3}}}\over{^{52}C_{13}}}$$