Total Probability of Bridge hands
For the question "Find the probability of being dealt a bridge hand of 13 cards containing 5 spades, 2 hearts, 3 diamonds, and 3 clubs", the following awnser was given
$$\frac {\binom {13}5\times \binom {13}2\times \binom {13}3\times \binom {13}3}{\binom {52}{13}}$$
But how does one calculate the probability of getting any hand with a 5332 distribution? I know you can not multiply the awnser times 4, but is there an easy way to calculate the probability of being dealt a certain distribution in Bridge (5332), no matter the suit?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

None of that (in the original post) is right. Go here and learn https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Probability

Ah, thank you Terrace. So all of these questions on this website, which were labelled as solved, are wrong according to you?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694814/probability-of-bridge-hands-using-distributions
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520913/stats-and-probability-question

I have edited your post to use standard notation and formatting.  I think that some confusion was caused by  writing things like "$52$ over $13$" when it seems clear (to me, at least) that you actually intended $\binom {52}{13}$.  If I have changed your meaning, please correct it or you can roll back to the original.

That said, This your question is really just "how many ways can we label the suits given that the distribution is $5,3,3,2$"".   But, then, just choose the two equal suits and then pick the $5$.  Alternately, just order the four suits, $4!$ ways, and divide by $2$ since $ABCD$ is the same as $ACBD$.

You say : "I know you can not multiply the awnser times 4" ; what is your logiq beyond this factor 4 ?? lulu gave the correct factor.
